# Construction of a linear Weingarten surface from a space curve

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

In Ivey and Landsberg's book *Cartan for Beginners*, the end paragraph of example 5.8.2 claims that linear Weingarten surfaces can be constructed by a space curve. They cite an older book from 1945 that is in French (*Les Systemes Exterieurs et leurs Applications Geometriques*) which explicitly carries out this construction.

I don't know French and I can't seem to find an English translation. Does anyone know of an English version? If not, does anyone know this construction and could give a brief outline of how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll find a discussion of the analysis of linear Weingarten surfaces via exterior differential systems in [these lecture notes of mine](https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/MSRI_Lectures.pdf).  Particularly look at Section 5.1, where it is discussed at length.  If you've already read Ivey and Landsberg, this should be fairly accessible.

I should say that this is not original work.  The exposition is based on the treatment in Élie Cartan's book *Les systèmes différentiels extérieurs et leurs applications géométriques*.  It's not exactly a translation, because Cartan did not use the same kind of 'set theory' language that we do now, but it's the same in spirit.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought perhaps the book was referring to some kind of explicit formula to write down a linear Weingarten surface. Maybe something similar to Bjorling's construction of a minimal surface from a space curve. Not sure why I was expecting that. Thank you!

Comment: @TK-421:  I see.  Actually, it's natural to ask whether there is such an explicit formula as the Weierstrass formula (of which Bjorling's formula is a special case) for other linear Weingarten relations, and the 19th century geometers did ask that question.  In fact, Lie and Darboux completely solved that problem, and the answer is essentially 'no'.   For example, Lie showed that the equation $K=c$, where $c$ is a nonzero constant, cannot be explicitly solved in terms of two arbitrary functions of one variable and any finite number of derivatives and integral extensions.